# Listing a TAR archive in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tar

I'm currently trying to figure out how to list a (gzipped) TAR archive in Haskell. [`Codec.Archive.Tar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tar-0.4.0.1/docs/Codec-Archive-Tar.html) seems to be the right choice for the task, but I can't figure out how `map` the `entryPath` over the `Entries` monoid.

Let's assume the TAR contains the entries (only files) `a.txt, b.txt, c.txt` and is named `foo.tar.gz`. Here's my code to read the file:

```
import qualified Codec.Archive.Tar as Tar
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Codec.Compression.GZip as GZip

foldEntryToPath :: Tar.Entry -> [String] -> [String]
foldEntryToPath entry list = list ++ [show $ Tar.entryPath entry]

-- Converts TAR errors to a string.
entryFailMapper :: String -> [String]
entryFailMapper err = [err]

main = do
        fileContent <- fmap GZip.decompress $ BS.readFile "foo.tar.gz"
        entries <- fmap Tar.read fileContent :: Tar.Entries
        -- Here I don't know how to correctly apply fmap
        entryPaths <- Tar.foldEntries foldEntryToPath [] entryFailMapper entries :: [String]
        -- This should print ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]
        print entryPaths
```

Here's the error printed by `runghc`:

```
readtar.hs:14:49:
Expecting one more argument to `Tar.Entries'
In an expression type signature: Tar.Entries
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  entries <- fmap Tar.read fileContent :: Tar.Entries
In the expression:
  do { fileContent <- fmap GZip.decompress
                      $ BS.readFile "foo.tar.gz";
       entries <- fmap Tar.read fileContent :: Tar.Entries;
       entryPaths <- Tar.foldEntries
                       foldEntryToPath [] (\ x -> [...]) entries ::
                       [String];
       print entryPaths }
```

So far I have little knowledge of Haskell, but by reading [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tar-0.4.0.1/docs/Codec-Archive-Tar.html) I don't know why `Tar.Entries` is a typeclass (is that the correct term when it says `expecting n more arguments to <type>`?) or what's the correct type to use.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: note that this isn't the latest version of the lib.

Comment: @Vektorweg Thanks, I didn't notice that (I updated the links!). However this were just the doc links (found them via google in the first place), I installed the lib using `cabal install tar` which actually installed 0.4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of fiddling around, I now have a full working example.

One of the main problems was the `foldr`-like behaviour of `Tar.foldEntries`. In reality, I have a ~25GB TAR file containing a few millions of entries. See [the HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27) for information on why this is a bad idea. (Note: Being efficient wasn't the question, but I think the `foldEntries`-free solution is better for this specific usecase.

Therefore I wrote my own recursive `Tar.Entries -> [String]` mapping function. Even if errors currently aren't handled particularly well, it should provide a good starting point.

```
import qualified Codec.Archive.Tar as Tar
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Codec.Compression.GZip as GZip

entriesToPaths :: Tar.Entries Tar.FormatError -> [String]
entriesToPaths (Tar.Next entry entries) = [Tar.entryPath entry] ++ entriesToPaths entries
entriesToPaths Tar.Done = [] :: [String]
entriesToPaths (Tar.Fail e) = ["Error"]

main = do
        fileContent <- fmap GZip.decompress $ BS.readFile "foo.tar.gz"
        let entries = Tar.read fileContent
        let entryPaths = entriesToPaths entries
        -- This should print ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]
        print entryPaths
```

Comment: I don't get your negative remark about foldr in this case, as your entriesToPaths function is just a hand-written foldr.

Comment: @kosmikus I think you are right. I was originally thinking that I implemented foldl, but that is not the case. However, the `foldEntries`-based solution still thrashed my computer, while it didn't with my own implementation. I'll check your solution again tomorrow, maybe the issues were not caused by `foldEntries` itself, but by another statement.

Comment: Well, in your question, in `foldEntryToPath`, you're appending the new element to the *end* of the list. That's not going to be efficient, ever. In this solution, in `entryToPaths`, you're appending the new entry to the beginning. So this difference is the important one. Not whether you use `foldEntries` or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think `foldEntryToPath` needs to be fixed:

```
foldEntryToPath :: Tar.Entry -> [String] -> [String]
foldEntryToPath entry list = (show $ Tar.entryPath entry) : list
```

And in `main`:

```
fileContent <- fmap GZip.decompress $ BS.readFile "foo.tar.gz"
let entries = Tar.read fileContent
let entryPaths = Tar.foldEntries foldEntryToPath [] entryFailMapper entries
print entryPaths
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I got my own code working just seconds before your post. As far as I can see, with your changes, the code works fine, however the `foldr`-like `foldEntries` behaviour exhibits some severe performance issues in some cases (however I didn't specifically ask for performance and/or memory efficiency, so your post is still correct). See my answer for an alternate solution with a `foldEntries` replacement.

Comment: When I apply your changes to the code from the question, I get this error in line 15: `Couldn't match type `Tar.FormatError' with '[Char]'`. Can you reproduce this issue?